# Powershell format-table error

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to run the following code to retrieve a list of local users on a machine.

```
gwmi win32_useraccount -Computername $env:computername -Filter "Domain='$env:computername'" |
  Format-Table Name,Description
```

I get this error when running inside a PS1 file:

```
 The object of type
 "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" is not
 valid or not in the correct sequence. This is likely caused by a
 user-specified "f ormat-table" command which is conflicting with the
 default formatting.
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [out-lineoutput],
 InvalidOperationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
 ConsoleLineOutputOutOfSequencePacket,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand
```

I understand this issue arises because of the way the pipelines are parsed but I can't figure out how to get around it.

Answer (score 23):

The `Format-*` cmdlets do not do final output, but transform their input into a sequence of formatting objects. These formatting objects are converted to the actual output by one of the `Out-` cmdlets, probably `Out-Default`.

If a script has multiple, different, sets of formatting objects that final output of the merged objects from all the expressions in the script `Out-Default` cannot resolve the inconsistencies.

Fix: add a `Out-Sting` to the end of each output generating pipeline to perform the formatting one expression at a time:

```
gwmi win32_useraccount -Computername $env:computername -Filter "Domain='$env:computername'" |
  Format-Table Name,Description | Out-String
```

Comment: I do not reproduce with this command on my seven, But it appends to me with other WMI class.

Comment: @manojlds The problem comes when running multiple output producing statements together in a single execution. You can get the same on the command line by having two commands together on a single command line with the `;` statement separator. In some cases it works, in others it doesn't. But forcing output to be strings which are displayed directly has always worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try :

```
gwmi win32_useraccount -Computername $env:computername -Filter "Domain='$env:computername'"  | Select-Object Name,Description  | Format-Table Name,Description
```

In fact you convert to an intermediate `PSCustomObject` and you still have an object.